# Targeting single instance of css class with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I need to target a single instance of a class, using JQuery, because I need to insert a new chunck of html code after (or before) an element on the page. My first thought was to use the "inserAfter" method. But, I soon realized it was a common class used several times in the document. The default syntax is like this, I believe:

```
$('<p>Test</p>').insertAfter('.inner');
```

I read that you can use siblings method, but I dont' see how I can combine the insertAfter/Before, and also, the instances of the class are identical - from body down to the actual content. So it's about targeting the second instance out of 5 (instances) or something and insert bla, bla code.

Is it possible? Or should I re-think the whole plan and... do something else? 
Thanks for any ideas, hints or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eq()` to target a specific instance of a class based on index. As it starts at zero, `eq(1)` would be the second instance of the class `.inner` :

```
$('.inner').eq(1).after('<p>Test</p>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.inner:nth-of-type(2)').after('<p>Test</p>');
```

**Source(s)**

[jQuery API - nth-of-type() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/)